# Remote nx monorepo freezing vscode IntelliSense

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I'm working on a project which was created using [Nx Monorepo with module federation plugin](https://nx.dev/recipes/module-federation/module-federation-with-ssr). Currently, this project has a host folder and a remote folder in /apps. It was working fine but suddenly when I added a new component inside a modulo from the remote folder vscode IntelliSense stopped working.

[image]

I got stuck on this Loading... and if I try to open any file and use vscode IntelliSense, it just doesn't work. If I reload vscode and open the HOST(shell) project or sales-panel module. It works, but if I get into sales-input module, open a file, then go back to sales-panel module and try to use IntelliSense, It doesn't work.

I've tried too many things, like updating the ts version and using another IDE as WebStorm and nothing worked. I've already worked on a project with much more files and it didn't happen. I feel like is something caused by NX.